# Why doesn't my Event Handler fire when I click on a radio button?

Tags: button, events, radio-button, handler

I have a table in the HTML with 8 columns.  The header row is manually populated in the HTML as below.

```
            <asp:Table ID="courseTable" runat="server" CssClass="table table-lg" style="color:white">
                    <asp:TableRow>   
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Choose One</b></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Course Name and Title</b></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Width="101"><b>Course Dates</b></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Building</b></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Meeting Times</b></asp:TableCell>                        
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Days of Week</b></asp:TableCell>                     
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Location</b></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><b>Term</b></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
```

and the code behind is used to populate more rows (with a radio button in the first column)

```
                //Add new row to table
                courseTable.Rows.Add(new TableRow());

                //Add Cells to new rows
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                {
                    courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                }

                //Create radio button for new row
                RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton();
                rdo.ID = response.Sections[i].ToString();
                rdo.Text = response.Sections[i].ToString();
                rdo.CheckedChanged += rdo_CheckedChanged(rdo, new EventArgs());

                //Add buttons and info to table (add 1 since the titles count as a row)
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Controls.Add(rdo);
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[1].Text = response.NameTitle[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Text = response.SecDates[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Text = response.BuildingRoom[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[4].Text = response.MeetingTime[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[5].Text = response.Days[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[6].Text = response.Location[i].ToString();
                courseTable.Rows[i + 1].Cells[7].Text = response.Term[i].ToString();
            }

        }

        protected EventHandler rdo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("clicked"); //test message box 
            cscId.Value = (sender as RadioButton).ID;

            return null;
        }
```

but the Event Handler only fires when the radio buttons are added dynamically to each row.  The Event Handler never fires when the user clicks on one of the radio buttons.   Thanks for any info.

the test message box within the Event Handler was added to verify this

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who may have this problem...
The reason the event was not firing is because the radio button needed    AutoPostBack="true"  set.  But, unfortunately, the post back messes up the screen because the table was created dynamically.
I'll have to use a GridView control I guess. :(